# Loading config files producing null in Java

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to load a config file in a custom way from a path. When I load the file, I get no errors, but when I reference loaded values I get null and when I attempt to close the file I get a NullPointerException. Here's everything:

[Main Class](https://pastebin.com/NzfjcUsG)

[ConfigHandler Class](https://pastebin.com/XEpMV3nb)

File to load:

```
test:one
hello:two
world:three
```

Console output:

```
nullnullnullnull
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at config.ConfigHandler.closeConfig(ConfigHandler.java:54)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Anyone got any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Also I saw you are *swallowing exception* which is not good practice..

Comment: Please paste [the relevant part of] your code in the question.

Comment: @SagarRohankar I know that the NullPointerException is being caused by file.close in ConfigHandler.

Comment: NPE is getting thrown at line `ConfigHandler.java:54`, and that line is `file.close();` So can you guess what's might wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ready boolean is never set true so the file is never initialized(its initialized null) in the constructor of ConfigHandler.Is there a reason for using the ready flag?If yes then write something to make it true as your code uses it at multiple places

Comment: All fixed now. Thanks!